# JAXB prefixes String with white space

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I created a java bean out of an `xsd` as follows:

```
<xs:attribute name="Text" type="xs:string" use="optional">

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Text")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2016-04-26T09:32:35+02:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
    protected String text;
```

When I send the XML request to the `SOAP webservice`, any text written in that string gets *prefixed* with a white space

So if I write `myclass.setText("TEST")` the `XML` will be <..  text=" TEST" />`.

The setter and getter methods are not called anywhere else.

What is the reason behind it; can give me some pointers on it. Other strings are fine without prefix, but this single string somehow behaves different.